# CSS: Overflow in a DIV horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, scroll, overflow

I'm developing an application that contains a table made ​​by div. The divs are filled according to the results database. 
As you can see in the image below.

[image]

However, if I put one more item on the bench, just disrupting the entire table. What I would do is to put a rod horizontally so that it could rotate it and so see the other items in the database without messing up the structure.

[image]

CODE

CSS

```
        #fundo {
         display: block;
         height: 550px; 
         margin-left: -3%;
         overflow: scroll;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         width: 1150px;
        }

        .vacina, .dose, .aplicacao {
         background-color: #D3D3D3;
         border-radius: 5px;
         float: left;
         height: 90px;
         margin-top: 6px;
         margin-left: 6px;
         position: relative; 
         width: 100px; 
        }

    .vacina {
    height: 50px;
    }
```

PHP

```
include_once ("db.php");
$sql = "SELECT nomeVacina FROM vacina ORDER BY cod";
 $ds1=mysql_query($sql);


if ($ds1) {
     if (mysql_num_rows($ds1) > 0) {
            $x = 0;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////// DIV VACINA /////////////////

            while($linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds1)) {
                $x++;

                if(!($linha['nomeVacina'] == "Outras")) {


                            echo "<div class='vacina' id='".$x."'>";
                            echo "<br>".$linha['nomeVacina'];
                            echo "</div>";

                    }

                }
            }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////// FIM DIV VACINA /////////////





        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////// DIV DOSE ///////////////////


            for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
                echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br>";
                echo "<div class='dose'>";

                if($i == 4 || $i == 5) {
                    echo "<br>Reforco";
                }

                else {
                    echo "<br>Dose ".$i;
                }
                echo "</div>";

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////// FIM DIV DOSE ///////////////






            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            ////////////////// DIV APLICACAO //////////////

                $z=0;
                for($j = 1; $j <= $x; $j++) {

                    $sql2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dataAplicacao, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dataAplicacao, loteVacina, descricaoVacina FROM vacinaaplicada WHERE dose = ".$i." AND codigoVacina = ".$j." AND codPaciente = '".$cns."'";
                        $ds2=mysql_query($sql2);
                    $linha2=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds2);

                    $z++;
                    echo "<div class='aplicacao' id='".$z.$i."'>";

                    if($linha2 == "") {
                        echo "";
                    }

                    else {
                        echo "<div style='margin-top:10px;'>". $linha2['descricaoVacina']."<div class='fonte'><b>Data</b><br></div>". $linha2['dataAplicacao'] . "<div class='fonte'><b>Lote</b><br></div>".$linha2['loteVacina']."</div>" ;
                    }

                    echo "</div>";
                }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            ////////////////// FIM DIV APLICACAO /////////////
            }
```

[image]

As you can see in the previous image, has 9 div class Vacina.

If I add a div class Vacina the most, will mess up the table.

What I'd like is to insert more than 9 div class Vacina causing the background div (div class includes all div) increase in width, but leaving it the same way the image, just putting a scroll bar horizontally to display whole div.

Comment: Details added on first post

Comment: I don't see any `<div>`s at all here. Where are they? **Edit:** I see, the markdown processor was hiding them. You should review your posts when you make them to make sure that everything that should be visibile is visible. You should also provide an example of what your actual HTML code looks like rather than making us wade through your PHP.

Comment: The php code does the following: 

first makes a search of vaccines registered in the database. 

While receiving data in this table, creates a div class Vacina placing one beside the other. 

Then he puts on the line below for a div class dose showing dose of Vacina and beside this dose Vacina. 

If the Vacina was not been applied, fills the blank div.

Comment: Ok, but you should still provide the HTML that is manifesting the problem. The PHP code isn't really relevant here since this question is about HTML presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I'd try this:

To `#fundo`, add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

And I replaced `float: left;` with:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Maybe that's what you're looking for.

EDIT:
Okay, I've built an example from scratch (but using javascript, not php, I can't test php atm): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxSeg/).
It's a bit messy but you should be able to code it in PHP if you like to.
Let me know if you've got trouble with this.
EDIT 2:
Just to have it in the answer (not just in its comments), the final solution is: [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjY5A/).

Comment: Not yet. What I wanted to do was increase the size of the background div, but without that size were visible. She would continue with the current size of the div, but put a scroll bar to view the rest of the size of div

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to say, sorry.I thought you want your table to have a fixed width for the visible part and a scroll bar when the table is wider than the visible part so you can scroll through the rest of the table. Not what you wanted?

Comment: That's weird because I can do that with what I've posted here.

Comment: Here are two images of the same table, but one with a zoom of 90% and the other with 100% zoom. I would like to stay like the image zoom 90%, just adding a scrollbar to see everything without any overlaps another div. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8gWXq.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/PVetZ.png

Comment: would you please provide the html code of your document? It's kinda difficult without.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed yet, I've added a jsfiddle to my post.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm almost there. the problem now is that when you have too much text in the content div ultiam line, the entire column goes up http://i.stack.imgur.com/5iRP0.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/ub3Dg.png

Comment: and the divs created in javascript, I can not use them with the click on it using jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JjY5A/ fixed column thing (check .col class in css) and added IDs for content boxes so you can access them with jQuery (also made examples for that)

Answer (score 0):

HTML + PHP

```
<?php
  include_once("sessao.php");

  if (!isset($_SESSION['funcionario']['cpfFuncionario'])) {
    header("Location:index.html");
  }

  else if($_SESSION['funcionario']['adicionarDireito'] == 0) {
    header("Location:funcionario.php");
  }

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Vacina Digital - Cadastrar Vacinação</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/reset.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/fonts.css"> 

    <style>

     body {
        background-color:  #fdfdfd;
        overflow-y: auto; 
      }


      #form {

            margin-left: 50px;
            padding-left: 7%;
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #0F935A;
            border-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
      }

      #form h1 {
          text-align: center;
          margin-right: 150px;
          font-family: "RobotoCondensed";
          font-size: 30px;
      }


    </style>   












  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
        include_once 'menufuncionario.php';
    ?>


    <div id="form">
      <fieldset>
        <?php
            include_once("db.php");
            if(isset($_POST['cns'])) {
              $cns = $_POST['cns'];
              $_SESSION['paciente'] = $cns;
            }
            else{
              $cns = $_SESSION['paciente'];
            }
            $sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'data' FROM  populacao WHERE codigoCns = ".$cns;

            $ds1=mysql_query($sql);

            if ($ds1) {
              if (mysql_num_rows($ds1) > 0) {



                  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM vacinaaplicada WHERE codPaciente = ".$cns;
                  $ds2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                  $linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds2);


                  $linha2=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds1);
                  $data_nasc = $linha2['data'];

                  $data_nasc=explode("/",$data_nasc);
                  $data=date("d/m/Y");
                  $data=explode("/",$data);
                  $anos=$data[2]-$data_nasc[2];
                  if ($data_nasc[1] > $data[1]) {
                  $anos = $anos-1;
                  } if ($data_nasc[1] == $data[1]) {
                  if ($data_nasc[0] <= $data[0]) {
                  $anos = $anos;

                  } else {
                  $anos = $anos-1;

                  }
                  } if ($data_nasc[1] < $data[1]) {
                  $anos = $anos;
                  }

                  $data2=date("d/m/Y");
                  echo "<h1>Carteira de Vacinação - ".$linha2['nomeCrianca']."</h1>";
                  /*echo "

                  <div id='caderneta' style='margin-left:-6%'>
                  ";*/

                  include_once 'caderneta.php';
                  echo "







                  </div>";

              } else {
                  echo "<h1>CNS Inválido</h1><br><br>
                  <center><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'><button  style='margin-left:-150px' class='button button-red' href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'>Voltar</button></a></center>
                  ";
              }
            }


      ?>

    </div>




  </body>

</html>
```

Caderneta

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/fonts.css"> 
<style type="text/css">


    #fundo {
    min-width: 800px;
     display: block;
     overflow: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     margin-left: -3%;
     height: 550px; 

     white-space: nowrap;
    }




    #pinguim, .vacina, .dose, .aplicacao {
        width: 100px; 
        height: 90px; 
        background-color: #D3D3D3; 
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }




    #pinguim, .vacina {
        height: 50px;

    }

    .vacina, .dose{
        background: green;
        font-family: RobotoCondensed;
        font-size: 14pt;
        text-align: center;

        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .vacina{
        padding-top: -14px;
        line-height: 15px;
    }

    .dose, .aplicacao{
        margin-top: -32px;  
    }

    .dose{
        line-height: 29px; 
    }

    .aplicacao, .fonte {
        font-family: "RobotoLight";
        text-align: center;
    }









</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "fundo">


    <div id = "pinguim">        
    </div>


    <?php
    include_once ("db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT nomeVacina FROM vacina ORDER BY cod";
    $ds1=mysql_query($sql);


    if ($ds1) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($ds1) > 0) {
            $x = 0;
            $k = 0;
            while($linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds1)) {
                $x++;

                if(!($linha['nomeVacina'] == "Outras")) {


                        echo "<div class='vacina' id='".$x."'>";
                        echo "<br>".$linha['nomeVacina'];
                        echo "</div>";

                }
            }


            for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
                echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br>";

                echo "<div class='dose'>";

                if($i == 4 || $i == 5) {
                    echo "<br>Reforco";
                }

                else {
                    echo "<br>Dose ".$i;
                }
                echo "</div>";



                $z=0;
                for($j = 1; $j <= $x; $j++) {

                    $sql2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dataAplicacao, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dataAplicacao, loteVacina, descricaoVacina FROM vacinaaplicada WHERE dose = ".$i." AND codigoVacina = ".$j." AND codPaciente = '".$cns."'";
                    $ds2=mysql_query($sql2);
                    $linha2=mysql_fetch_assoc($ds2);

                    $z++;
                    echo "<div class='aplicacao' id='".$z.$i."'>";

                    if($linha2 == "") {
                        echo "";
                    }

                    else {
                        echo "<div style='margin-top:10px;'>". $linha2['descricaoVacina']."<div class='fonte'><b>Data</b><br></div>". $linha2['dataAplicacao'] . "<div class='fonte'><b>Lote</b><br></div>".$linha2['loteVacina']."</div>" ;
                    }

                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }





            echo"</div>";











        }

    }




    ?>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```